# Definition of the binomial coefficient $a_{n}=\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, factorial

Applying the definition of the binomial coefficient I can't figure out how to simplify the following expression:

$$a_{n}=\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}$$

I want to find:

$$a_{n}=(-1)^n\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n-1)!2^{2n}n!}$$

I'm stuck at the beginning. 
$$a_{n}=\frac{-\frac{1}{2}!}{n!\left ( n-\frac{1}{2} \right )!}$$

Thank you so much!

Comment: Write it out as $\frac{-\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{2}-1 \right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}-2\right)\cdots \left(-\frac{1}{2}-n+1 \right)}{n!}$. Take out a minus from each of the $n$ factors in the numerator. To simplify further multiply the fraction by $\frac{2^n}{2^n}$ and multiply in a factor of $2$ to each of the terms in the numerator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing $\binom{2n}{n} = (-4)^n \binom{-1/2}{n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102075/showing-binom2nn-4n-binom-1-2n). See also [Generalized binomial coefficient](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584048/generalized-binomial-coefficient)

Comment: @Winther: While the accepted answer to the question that you cite also answers this question, this is obviously not a duplicate.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott It's obviously not not obviously not. Anyway, I don't have strong feelings about it. If non of those answers does satisfy OPs needs and he/she wants answers that explains other aspects of this computation (like the title hints towards) then OP should just say so and I'll remove the vote.

Answer (score 1):

Here we use the following definition of the *[binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series)* 
\begin{align*}
  \binom{\alpha}{n}=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}
\qquad\qquad\alpha\in\mathbb{C},\quad n\in \mathbb{N}\tag{1}
  \end{align*}
It is also convenient to use *[double factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)* for a more compact notation
\begin{align*}
  (2n)!! &= (2n)(2n-2)\cdots 4\cdot2\qquad\qquad\qquad n\in\mathbb{N}\\
  (2n-1)!! &= (2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots 3\cdot1\\
  \end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}&=\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}-1\right)
>   \cdots\left(-\frac{1}{2}-n+1\right)}{n!}\tag{2}\\
>   &=\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)
>   \cdots\left(-\frac{2n-1}{2}\right)}{n!}\\
>   &=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}\cdot\frac{1\cdot 3\cdots \
>   \left(2n-1\right)}{n!}\tag{3}\\
>   &=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}\cdot\frac{(2n-1)!!}{n!}\tag{4}\\
>   &=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}\cdot\frac{(2n)!}{(2n)!!n!}\tag{5}\\
>   &=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}\cdot\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!n!}\tag{6}\\
>   &=\frac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!n!}\tag{7}\\
>   &=\frac{(-1)^n(2n-1)!}{2^{2n-1}(n-1)!n!}\tag{8}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the definition of the binomial coefficient with $\alpha=-\frac{1}{2}$
- In (3) we factor out $-\frac{1}{2}$ from each of the $n$ factors giving $(-1)^n\frac{1}{2^n}$
- In (4) we use double factorials $(2n-1)!!$
- In (5) we apply $$(2n)!=(2n)!!(2n-1)!!$$
- In (6) we use the formula from (5) and note that

$$(2n)!!=(2n)(2n-2)\cdots4\cdot 2=2^nn!$$

- In (7) we collect terms.
- In (8) we devide numerator and denominotor by $2n$.

Note there is a factor $2^{2n-1}$ in the denominator of $a_n$ which gives for $n=1$
\begin{align*}
\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{1}=-\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}