# Binomial Coefficients $ {\frac{-1}{2} \choose n}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, pochhammer-symbol

i am trying to solve Exercises from Martin Aigner A Copurse in Enummarations, i am having problems with this one: 
[image: img]

I got the first part(well you open the factorials by definition and put the 2's in the right positions, then close), but I am clueless where to start on the second one.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102075/showing-binom2nn-4n-binom-1-2n

Comment: awesome! :) this helps

Comment: Hint: Try letting $r = -1/2$.